# Android. In setFlag(int flags, int mask). Why are flags and mask identical?

Tags: android

Explanation in the documentation:

- flags    int: The new window flags
- mask     int: Which of the window flag bits to modify.

I'm just trying to set the full screen when the activity is loaded by using
   getWindow().setFlag(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

It works but I just don't understand the meaning behind the method's parameters.
I'm thinking that *flags* is the look I want for the current window, but I don't know what *mask* does and why is it identical to *flags*

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html      go to constant

Comment: The accepted answer is OK. But I think this one is even better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47854714/2816119 specially this part: "The math is basically ((getFlags &~mask) | (value & mask))"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would have googled, you could have found this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)), which can explain to you the idea of a mask. Basically is a bit-wise filter against another value. Very common when coding C and C++ for example, less in Java, almost not used anymore when coding Android, but of course still used by the system because are very fast operations (at the bits level).
Using a mask which is the same as the value, means no filtering. You can accomplish the very same with other masks as well, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However, I think I've stated my question unclear. I'm not asking what a mask is or what it generally does. I was confused by how the 2 parameters in the method setFlags() are always identical. Thus, I don't know what the "mask" parameter does in this method (I know that the "flags" parameter would be the state I want the window to be in).

Comment: I thought this answer that part: "Using a mask which is the same as the value, means no filtering.". Let me repeat it: it does nothing.

Comment: Oh my bad. I kept reading the article page you gave and forgot to read the last part of your comment. Thank you! It makes more sense now

Comment: If you look at the implementation, this is how they are filtered: _flags&mask_.

Comment: You're welcome! I think this was a very good curious question, worth to answer :)