# Android - BottomSheetDialog is under software NavigationBar

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationbar, bottom-sheet

I have a problem with BottomSheetDialog and software navigation bar. If I create BottomSheetDialog:

```
    BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mContext);
    View sheetView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_sentence, (ViewGroup)view.getParent(), false);
    mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView);
    mBottomSheetDialog.show();
```

then on devices with the software navigation bar, the dialog is shown below/under the navigation bar (in this example it's a tablet with Android 7.0, it's not so visible but the second button is below the navigation bar):

[image]

How can I add the BottomSheetDialog above the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

int theme= R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme;

BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog = newBottomSheetDialog( context, theme);

Add this code in style.xml

```
 <style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="BaseBottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I tried it but this is not working. I have to move somehow BottomSheetDialog above the navigation bar.

Comment: mBottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener(dialog1 ->
  {
   BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog1;
   FrameLayout bottomSheet = d.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
   BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
                      .setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
  });  //please add this piece of code after creating the object it is working i tried.

Comment: I tried it and still not working. The bottom part (second button) is still below navigation bar.

Comment: android:paddingBottom="@android:dimen/navigation_bar_height"                           // Add this piece of code to the view which is hiding behind the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you're not define window system UI flag.

please check this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47854623/10068068)

I'm usually use this method to prevent my single components or view group inflating under Soft Navigation Bar

```
MyActivity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
```

Comment: I tried it and still not working. The bottom part (second button) is still below navigation bar.